# It's not due "in" tomorrow

Tags: prepositions

I stumbled across this sentence while reading a book:

> It's not due **in** tomorrow.

**it** refers to a piece of homework.

After looking up the word "due" in several dictionaries, I suppose "due" means expected and "due in" is not a fixed phrase.

I wonder why they don't just say "It's not due tomorrow.". If a preposition is compulsory, why isn't it "on" because "tomorrow" is a day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, the preposition is [usually omitted](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=due+tomorrow%2Cdue+in+tomorrow&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3), but it's not *wrong*; [here](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/due) is a similar example from Lexico:

> Karen's train was *due in* soon after 2, so I made my way back to the station, having to squeeze through a thick colonnade of cyclists in order to do so.

It doesn't change the meaning, so "It's not due tomorrow." means the same and is much more common.

Comment: The homework is not due [to be handed] in. The train is due [to come] in [to the station].

Comment: I agree with @KateBunting that there is something elided, but I've always considered it differently: (1) *The assignment is not due in [the classroom] until tomorrow.* (2) *The train is not due in [the station] until tomorrow.* Using *in*, to me, always implies an elided prepositional object—not an elided verbal phrase.